# Customizing how values get displayed in a Liferay SearchContainer

Tags: liferay-6.2, searchcontainer

My Liferay entity `Person` has a `<column name="mother" type="long" />` which points to the primary key of another instance of `Person`. This long shows up as a number in the [SearchContainer](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/SearchContainer) table I created:

```
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
        name="category"
        property="category"
    />
```

Now, instead of showing up as a long I would like to display the name of the person. So I wrote:

```
    <%
        String motherName =
            PersonLocalServiceUtil.getPerson( person.getMother() )
                .getName();
        }
    %>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
        name="mother"
        value="<%= motherName %>"
        property="mother"
    />
```

**PROBLEM**: The values that get displayed in this column are still the `long` numbers, not the name. Even after rebuilding and restarting.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the implementation of `SearchContainerColumnTextTag`:

```
public int doEndTag() {
    ...
    if (Validator.isNotNull(_property)) {
        _value = ...
    }
```

As you can see, you can't set both, `property` and `value`. Just set `value` and you are fine.